# Algorithm to break down item for chrome storage sync

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to save a string (correction: it is an object containing multiple strings of varying sizes) using chrome.storage.sync.set but am receiving the error:
Error: QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM quota exceeded

this is due to the limit being 8092 so I want to break the string down into multiple parts and then be able to reconstruct it when retrieving them.

my code that is giving the existing error is below.

```
 var obj = {};
  obj[workspaceName] = stringToSave;  
  chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      return customAlert("Error!: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
  });
```

Is there an existing function or code that would help me to do this?

Comment: You can use the standard string manipulation functions such as [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice). You may want to compress the source first by using LZString library or a similar one.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the part I am more curious about is an algorithm for storing/retrieving the object that needs to broken down. almost like a linked list implementation for storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing: generate an object like `{foo0: chunkA, foo1: chunkB, foo2: chunkC, foo#: 3}`.

```js
function chunkedWrite(key, value) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (typeof key !== 'string') key = `${key}`;
    const str = JSON.stringify(value); // consider using LZString's compressToUTF16
    const len = chrome.storage.sync.QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM - key.length - 4;
    const num = Math.ceil(str.length / len);
    const obj = {};
    obj[key + '#'] = num;
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      obj[key + i] = str.substr(i * len, len);
    }
    chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, resolve);
  });
}
```

Reading is two-part: read the number of keys first, then read all the keys at once.

```js
function chunkedRead(key) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (typeof key !== 'string') key = `${key}`;
    const keyNum = key + '#';
    chrome.storage.sync.get(keyNum, data => {
      const num = data[keyNum];
      const keys = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        keys[i] = key + i;
      }
      chrome.storage.sync.get(keys, data => {
        const chunks = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
          chunks.push(data[key + i] || '');
        }
        const str = chunks.join('');
        resolve(str ? JSON.parse(str) : undefined);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Deleting is similar to reading: read key#, then delete the array of keys.

```js
function chunkedDelete(key) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (typeof key !== 'string') key = `${key}`;
    const keyNum = key + '#';
    chrome.storage.sync.get(keyNum, data => {
      const num = data[keyNum];
      const keys = [keyNum];
      for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        keys.push(key + i);
      }
      chrome.storage.sync.remove(keys, resolve);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with the retrieve and this helped!

Comment: I think a small tweak is needed. After the for statement, add keys[num] = keyNum; to also delete the key with the number of chunks

Comment: Ah, I missed the word "delete", thanks for the correction.

Comment: Using QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM as max string length will fail if the string to be stored contains characters that use more than one byte per character. To avoid this encode the string with `btoa()` after stringifying it. And decode with `atob()` before JSON.parsing it.